# Can Gedit or Gvim copy multiple seperate lines to the clipboard (maybe by using bookmarks, or a script or another editor)

Tags: text-editor

I want to copy many "selected" full lines to the clipboard...  The lines are typically seperated from each other in the file...

Is either *`Gedit`* or *`Gvim`* capable of this? ... What I would prefer is to only need press a  single key to *mark* a line (like F2 .. but I think that Vim would need more keystrokes :( ... The next step I envisage, is another key(combo) to copy all the "selected" lines to the clipboard...

I'm open to other suggestions of how to do this; maybe there is some "block-mode".. but I do want it to be fast to select each line (must be a full line including the trailing newline)....
I've mentioned Gedit and Gvim as they are the most commonly used Ubuntu editors (I think)...but maybe another editor does this exact thing...

Maybe just appending to the clipboard will work. but that really is a *last resort!* as it is big-time error-prone... btw, I don't know the key-combo for appending to the clipboard, so I'd like to know about this too..,   thanks

PS. I've tried *Gedit's advanced-bookmarks* plugin, but it doesn't seem to do what I want ....

*Notepad++* has this *copy-all-bookmarked-lines* feature, but although it is open-source (based on SciTe), it only runs under `wine` and shows a few bugs in that environment.... but I'd really like a native Linux text editor for this ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `gedit` nor `gvim` have that capability.

Comment: It's starting to look that way, but I'll hang out for a while, 'til there are more views.... I'm amazed that Vim can't do it.. (but there may be a script for it lurking somewhere.... I've not used vim, other than for a quick look.. the keybinding of Emacs are easier for me, but both are a big learning curve...I think Emacs (and probably Vim) are capable of this, but in the meantime I've re-acquainted myself with Notepad++ (for this issue only)... I've also knocked up a *selection-append* script; it's handy, but it's clunky compared to bookmark selection control (eg. invert bookmarked lines...